Cycle through tabs in recently used order
In Firefox one can enable the option to cycle through tabs in the order they were recently used. I'd like the same in Emacs, but all resources I found talk about cycling through buffers, which is not what I'm looking for (as I already have something for that). Does anyone know about a way to cycle through recently used tabs?

Does the minor mode tab-bar-history-mode do what you want?

@NickD No, I want to switch between tabs in the order they were recently used, not restore an older window configuration of a tab. But also, what's the difference between this and winner-mode?

Winner mode is oblivious to tabs, so a tab switch is just considered yet another window layout.

@BramSchoenmakers Oh, I see, thanks! I guess I'll start to use tab-bar-history-mode then.

The switch-tab command offers completion and in combination with vertico it will order the tabs in recently used order.
